# How can I backup Meizu Pro5?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, backup

Is there a way how to back up my Meizu Pro5 Ubuntu phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.
I have tried to back-up Meizu Pro5 (Android originally)  from within TWRP recovery and it managed to back it up in about 2-3 min., including all data, system, cache, recovery, just tick all boxes when doing a backup.
Then I decided to test the backup and I was able to restore the phone from within TWRP just like it was an Android phone.
Back it up to your external sd and when anything happens while you play with your PRO5 you have a full backup to restore the phone.
This is handy when you want to try FLYME and want to come back to UBUNTU or vice versa.

Enjoy.